# android Blob image not loading

Tags: android, android-asynctask, blob, android-sqlite

here i want to display a image logo which i am receiving from a sqlite as blob database when i dont have internet, though i know its a not a good practice but i want to make it simpler this way.
Problem i am facing is i am able to receive image in log but some warning (link below) is coming because of which it is not loading it into imageView.

Here's the warning i am getting in log [image: http://i.imgur.com/paZ2ew0.png] !!

I am unable to figure out why it still running DownloadImageTask which is a async task even when not online that is isOnline()==false !!

```
   ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Logo);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(isOnline(this)==true);
    {
    String link = extras.getString("Logo1");
    new DownloadImageTask(logo).execute(link);
    }

           if(isOnline(this)==false){

    Log.d("offline","image");
    Log.d("offline",extras.getByteArray("Logo2").toString());    
    //getting these ^^ in log

            byte[] outImage=(byte[]) extras.getByteArray("Logo2");
        if(outImage!=null)
        {
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        logo.setImageBitmap(theImage);
       }


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(isOnline(this)==true)//you Superfluous add a ";" in this
    {
    String link = extras.getString("Logo1");
    new DownloadImageTask(logo).execute(link);
    }
```

i am a newbie,hope can help you

Comment: He means that you need to get rid of the semi-colon after the if statement.